# Google script .setFormula does not work well with proposed trigger for dawn

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

Hy Guys, I created a script to insert formula in a certain range and I created a trigger for this script to run between 01:00 and 02:00 AM, the goal is for it to subscribe the values with the formulas and then I can do the same process by pasting the resulting values, however, the formulas do not update and when the script that pastes the values runs, it pastes the Loading information, can you help me to solve?

[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gqN03.png)

[Trigger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XkFY1.png)

```js
function Formulas() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('CONTROLE DE CUSTOS');
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow()-1;
  sheet.getRange(2,8,lastRow,3).clearContent();
  sheet.getRange(2,8,lastRow,1).activate();
  spreadsheet.getActiveRange().setFormula('=SUM(QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("1RwCb30zr22uuIJUgeIrB9KMgxI2JgtSBKzQC0okI5yE";"Banco de Dados!A:F");"select Col4 where Col3 = \'"&INDIRECT(CONCATENATE("C";ROW()))&"\'"))');
  sheet.getRange(2,9,lastRow,1).activate();
  spreadsheet.getActiveRange().setFormula('=SUM(QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("1RwCb30zr22uuIJUgeIrB9KMgxI2JgtSBKzQC0okI5yE";"Banco de Dados!A:F");"select Col6 where Col3 = \'"&INDIRECT(CONCATENATE("C";ROW()))&"\'"))');
  sheet.getRange(2,10,lastRow,1).activate();
  spreadsheet.getActiveRange().setFormula('=IF(indirect(concatenate("F";row()))=0;0;(VLOOKUP(MID(indirect(concatenate("C";row()));find("[";indirect(concatenate("C";row()));2);500);TEMPLATE!A:E;5;0)*indirect(concatenate("F";row()))))');
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
};
```

Comment: Hello, could you paste your code in a code snippet ? :)

Comment: Hello, For sure! ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way:

```
function Formulas() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh = ss.getSheetByName('CONTROLE DE CUSTOS');
  var numrows = sh.getLastRow()-1;
  sh.getRange(2,8,numrows,3).clearContent();
  sh.getRange(2,8,numrows,1).setFormula('=SUM(QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("1RwCb30zr22uuIJUgeIrB9KMgxI2JgtSBKzQC0okI5yE";"Banco de Dados!A:F");"select Col4 where Col3 = \'"&INDIRECT(CONCATENATE("C";ROW()))&"\'"))');
  sh.getRange(2,9,numrows,1).setFormula('=SUM(QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("1RwCb30zr22uuIJUgeIrB9KMgxI2JgtSBKzQC0okI5yE";"Banco de Dados!A:F");"select Col6 where Col3 = \'"&INDIRECT(CONCATENATE("C";ROW()))&"\'"))');
  sh.getRange(2,10,numrows,1).setFormula('=IF(indirect(concatenate("F";row()))=0;0;(VLOOKUP(MID(indirect(concatenate("C";row()));find("[";indirect(concatenate("C";row()));2);500);TEMPLATE!A:E;5;0)*indirect(concatenate("F";row()))))');
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
}
```

Comment: Perfect! I'll try and tell u the result. Thanks a lot.